# how to use sqlite db created from core data after repopulating it on the server side?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I created sqlite db from core data and i want to repopulate it on the server side and download it again to device with overwriting existing sqlite db. Is it possible to repopulate on server side and is it work if overwrite with existing db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, if you are saving data through core data, it will create usual sqlite db, but all tables, field names will has a Z_ prefix.

You can simply use this db on the server side, that download it as file and overwrite exiting db on device.

Sorry for my broken english if something wrong.

Comment: thanks Vlad. I thought i can do. but core data uses different table structure relations, fields etc. and i'm not sure it will work. did you try something like this before?

Comment: it worked even though without filling some relation fields that automatically created via core data engine.

Answer (score 0):

Do not ever mess with a Core Data db outside of the application. In fact, forget it is a db because it is simply a storage mechanism.

What you need to do is to send the objects to the server (xml is probably the easiest), manipulate the data on the server, send the data back to the app, import the data into Core Data.

Comment: i know i'm trying unusual way but i have to do that way. if it works i will share here. thanks